# Installing/updating apps over mobile data

Tags: google-play-store, updates, installation, mobile-data, background-data

On my LG G2 device running Android 4.2.2, I can't seem to install or update any applications while on the mobile network. I can still access the Play Store but upon tapping "Update", the download progress bar remains at 0% and fails after a while (presumably timing out).

I have only restricted background data on YouTube and Instagram but I don't think this would affect the Play Store.

Is this problem solvable or was this done by design? I am not rooted and do not have intention of rooting the device.

Comment: Perhaps you're in a poor signal area in which downloads fail or that there's a cap limit?

Comment: I experience the problem no matter where I am, with LTE or 4G coverage, and I have plenty of data left for this billing cycle. Even on slow WiFi networks, updates still download slowly. They don't even start when I'm on the mobile network.

Comment: are you rooted? what android version? are you running something that is interfering with Google Play Services?

Comment: 4.2.2 and not rooted

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Could you enable the background data for all the apps and try updating. If it works, I assume the data restriction for Youtube is being applied to Google Play Services as well. It wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @k1chy It still did not work

Comment: Is it working via wifi update?

Comment: @user3275057 Yes, installing and updating apps over WiFi is the only way I can get them to install and update.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 then it may be problem with the mobile network. Did u tried in another network

Comment: @sameer No, there is nothing wrong with the mobile network as other people using Rogers Wireless can install updates over the mobile network. I've brought my device into the store and they tried resetting my plan but that didn't work either.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 are you restricting data usage for `media`. In your mobile goto `Settings-> Data Usage-> Mobile Tab-> Media`, un tick `restrict background data`. Now try.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 is it working now?

Comment: @sameer No it is still not working. Restrict background data was not checked for "Media".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it, as I had the same problem:

1. In the Settings go to Mobile Data.
2. Scroll down to item "Media" and tap it.
3. Scroll down and see if "Limit background data" is checked. If so, uncheck

This was the cause in my case, because for the Play Store app the same setting was not active. The problem with Android in this situation is, that there is a global setting "Limit background data" and there's a per app setting. Unchecking the global setting does not uncheck the per app setting. Doh!

Comment: Sorry, this should have been a comment.

Comment: This seems like an answer to me.

Comment: @infiniter this is an answer to the question so it should be an answer...